# Цикл из двух массивов

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Доброго времени суток.

Есть два массива:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array(a, b, c, d);
```

Как в php пересчитать элементы массива, чтобы они выглядели так:

```
1 элемент массива arr1 - 1 элемент массива arr2 - a
2 элемент массива arr1 - 2 элемент массива arr2 - b
2 элемент массива arr1 - 3 элемент массива arr2 - c
2 элемент массива arr1 - 4 элемент массива arr2 - d
```

ну или

```
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение

```
foreach($arr1 as $i=>$k) {

        echo "<p>".$k." - ".$k[$arr2]."</p>";
    }
```

Comment: `$arr2[$i]` тогда уж.

Comment: Откуда вообще $arr2 взяли в этом цикле?

Comment: Хай, и так будет. =)

Comment: IntegralAL а вы на мой вопрос посмотрите внимательнее.

Answer (score 4):

[привет любителям велосипедов](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

```
$combined = array_combine(array(1, 2, 3, 4,), array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd',)));
// [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c', 4 => 'd',]
```

Comment: Велосипеды наше все :DD
ps спасибо, буду знать про данную функцию

Comment: Да насчет велосипедов вы правы, спасибо за функцию, просто не нашел. Жаль только, что не сразу :) использовал свою комбинацию, но ставлю вам ответ, потому как очень красиво и аккуратно.

Comment: Честно хотел вам поставить, а оказывается, или сам себе поставил, или если отвечаешь на свой вопрос, то автоматом ставит ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array(a, b, c, d);
$res  = [];

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr1); $i++)
{ 
    $res[$arr1[$i]] = $arr2[$i];
}
```

Comment: А не покажите, как их вывести, как я просил, потому что у меня получается через var_dump следующие:

    array(1) { [1]=> string(1) "а" }
    array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "а" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
    array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "а" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c"}
    array(4) { [1]=> string(1) "а" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c"[4]=> string(1) "d"}

А мне надо ещё и организовать вывод, ну пусть как я вторым пример показывал.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php).

Answer (score 0):

Причём тут пхп? Вряд ли логика будет отличаться в других яп. А вот реализация будет, опять-таки не сильно. Можно ручками написать функцию для этого, а можно воспользоваться [решением из коробки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php).